# Creating a java Script function to make an api call and retrieve the data

Tags: javascript, github-api

A JavaScript function is needed to make an API call to Github and receive a response as JSON data.
The api link is as follows - https://api.github.com/users

Comment: **https://api.github.com/users** is itself the API

Comment: but how can i create a function to fetch the users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Axios` to fetch the data. Maybe you should consider reframing the question. How to get the users using **https://api.github.com/users**

```
const axios = require("axios");


async function getUsers() {
    try {
        let users = await axios.get('https://api.github.com/users');
        return {
            status: "SUCCESS",
            data: users
        }
    } catch (e) {
        return {
            status: "ERROR",
            data: ""
        }
    }
}


getUsers().then((users)=>{
    console.log(users.data);
}).catch(e => {
    console.log(e,"error while fetching users");
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
axios.get('https://api.github.com/users')
.then(response=> {
    console.log(response.data);
})
.catch(error => console.error(error));
```

I was able to obtain the users using this code

Comment: In question, you mentioned you wanted function.